# dynamic dropdown menu in as3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, actionscript

I've just started learning as3 and I've been trying to find a good tutorial on dropdown menu's using just xml and as3. Most of what I've come across so far are either static menus or menus driven with heavy use of the timeline. 
Is it even possible to build a nice fluid drop down menu completely in code?
If so and anyone has some good tutorials they would be greatly appreciated,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't take much to come up with a fluid dropdown menu. You could create a Button object that will take its properties from your XML. When all your button instances are created and stored in an Array/Vector, you can then use a Tween class for the animation.

Some tweener classes:

Tweener:
http://code.google.com/p/tweener/

TweenLite:
http://www.greensock.com/

Answer (score -1):

This one is not entirly in AS3 but you only have to buttons, all menu items are inside the code, very easy to adjust and you get the .fla as well

http://www.casualgamedesign.net/2011/06/simple-dropdown-menu-as3-fla/